# How can I start/stop/disable all VNC servers on Rocky Linux/Centos 8 with one command? (TigerVNC)

Tags: linux, systemctl, centos-8, tigervnc

Previously, wildcards were supported. E.g.

- sudo systemctl stop 'vncserver@*'
- sudo systemctl disable 'vncserver@*'

Now in Rocky Linux (and Centos-8 should be the same), the users are listed in "/etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users" instead of having separate service files. I could scan the file but is there one command that does them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcards (without quotes and --all appended) work for start,stop,restart and status. For enable/disable, I will scan the users file. E.g.

- sudo systemctl status vncserver@* --all

Comment: for disable, you need nothing but `vncserver@`. For start/stop, there's slice, I think.

Comment: "sudo systemctl disable vncserver@" worked for disable but not enable.  I found systemd.slice but I don't see a way to enable multiple instances. If the instances had not been started, I had to use "systemctl status vncserver@* --all". If they had been started, I did not have to add "--all".